# Unable to install Android packages

Tags: android

I'm setting up a new dev machine for Android development, and I'm suddenly unable to download packages. It always hangs at the Kyocera web page (quite interesting considering I didn't check anything regarding Kyocera) and won't continue. I tried this from two different networks.

I'm on a OS X machine, and just launched "android" and selected the Google APIs as well as the platform SDKs.

The message that I'm getting is always the same:

Failed to fetch URL http://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml/addon.xml, reason: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml/addon.xml

Is anybody else having this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, turns out that I didn't run "android" as a super user, which seems to be the cause of the problem. Just doing a "sudo android" solves the issue.

There is still that HTTP 403 error from Kyocera, but it doesn't seem to interfere with the installation of the other files. I just got sidetracked by that error.

Comment: I also contacted Kyocera, and they claim to have fixed the 403 error issue.

Comment: Mine just hung for about 45 seconds and then completed normally. If you cut and past the SDK's url into a browser, you can see what is happening - it is slooooow.

Answer (score 0):

a 403 error usually means you don't have permission to view that page. Interesting. Honestly unless you need to use Kyocera I just skipped that download. In AVD Manager when you go to available packages you should be able to check what you want to install and then install them and that was the only place I saw Kyocera.

Otherwise I'm not sure. sorry.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, I didn't check anything in regards to Kyocera. Thanks ...